# Am I right to get the address of sys_call_table this way with gdb?

Tags: gdb, linux-kernel

I'm now doing this way:

```
(gdb) info addr system_call
Symbol "system_call" is at 0xffffffff8100b920 in a file compiled without debugging.

(gdb) x/50i 0xffffffff8100b920
0xffffffff8100b920: swapgs 
0xffffffff8100b923: nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
0xffffffff8100b929: nopl   0x0(%rax)
0xffffffff8100b930: mov    %rsp,%gs:0xb008
0xffffffff8100b939: mov    %gs:0xb508,%rsp
0xffffffff8100b942: sti    
0xffffffff8100b943: sub    $0x50,%rsp
0xffffffff8100b947: mov    %rdi,0x40(%rsp)
0xffffffff8100b94c: mov    %rsi,0x38(%rsp)
0xffffffff8100b951: mov    %rdx,0x30(%rsp)
0xffffffff8100b956: mov    %rax,0x20(%rsp)
0xffffffff8100b95b: mov    %r8,0x18(%rsp)
0xffffffff8100b960: mov    %r9,0x10(%rsp)
0xffffffff8100b965: mov    %r10,0x8(%rsp)
0xffffffff8100b96a: mov    %r11,(%rsp)
0xffffffff8100b96e: mov    %rax,0x48(%rsp)
0xffffffff8100b973: mov    %rcx,0x50(%rsp)
0xffffffff8100b978: mov    %gs:0xb508,%rcx
0xffffffff8100b981: sub    $0x1fd8,%rcx
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
0xffffffff8100b988: testl  $0x100001d1,0x10(%rcx)
0xffffffff8100b98f: jne    0xffffffff8100bad0
0xffffffff8100b995: cmp    $0x12a,%rax
0xffffffff8100b99b: ja     0xffffffff8100ba5a
0xffffffff8100b9a1: mov    %r10,%rcx
0xffffffff8100b9a4: callq  *-0x7ec62ec0(,%rax,8)
```

Then `0x7ec62ec0` is the address of sys_call_table,right?

Comment: Are you debugging kernel stuff or user-space?

Comment: @stsquad,I'm just trying to get `sys_call_table`.

Comment: sys_call_table is visible to kernel space only. It should be listed in the System.map for the kernel image you have. What do you need it for?

Comment: Then what is `0x7ec62ec0 ` in my code above?

Comment: I need the address of that table to hijack the handler for 0x80 int.

Comment: This is why I asked if you are in kernel mode or user mode. If your debugging a kernel then it certainly looks like entry code into the system call. See http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S;h=8a445a0c989e095bc84557861d4a4e73e09e3e90;hb=HEAD the source code.

Answer (score 1):

> I need the address of that table to hijack the handler for 0x80 int.

Stop right there.  What are you *really* trying to do?  Hijacking an interrupt handler isn't your goal, it's one step you think you need to take to achieve something.  Whatever it is, you're probably going about this the wrong way.

To hijack interrupts, you need to change the [interrupt descriptor table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table).  I suggest you look at the [Intel reference manuals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table) to figure out how.  This will be painful programming.  But I suspect you're more interested in the system calls.  Also, on modern Linux systems, the `int 0x80` instruction is not the usual way of invoking a system call.  That of course still works for backwards compatibility, but you'll see other instructions out there like `sysenter` (x86) or `syscall` (x86_64).  So if you really are interested in doing something to system calls, don't do it in the interrupt handler.

Anyway, create a new question that asks for advice achieving your end goal, and the community here will help you through it.  If you have questions about specific parts, ask more questions and refer back to your high-level post in those new questions.

(BTW, if you want confirmation of the address, try running `info addr sys_call_table` in gdb.  Or, since it looks like you're on x86_64 architecture, try `p &sys_call_table`.)

Comment: Is `sys_call_table` a function?If not,what is it?

Comment: @compile-fan: `sys_call_table` is an array of function pointers.  For x86_64, it gets a real definition in C in the file [syscall_64.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_64.c).  For x86 (32-bit), it's just a symbol defined in assembly in the file [syscall_table_32.S](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S).

Comment: Isn't `sys_call_table` not exported any more in kernel 2.6.x ?But seems `info addr sys_call_table` still works,this is really weird!

Comment: @assem: The kernel only exports certain symbols that have been manually flagged.  But all the other symbols still exist in the kernel binary itself, since the kernel itself needs to be linked together.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your dump the `0x7ec62ec0` is the addres of `sys_call_table`. To get the full `sys_call_table` address you need to do the following:

```
sys_call_table = 0xFFFFFFFF00000000 | *(unsigned int *)(0xffffffff8100b9a4 + 3);
```

Here, `0xffffffff8100b9a4` is the addres of the `callq  *-0x7ec62ec0(,%rax,8)` instruction and 3 is the size. And don't forget that there may be several system call tables at the same time: `sys_call_table` and `ia32_sys_call_table` So, you'll need to handle all of the possible ways to do a system call: `int $0x80`, `syscall/sysenter`.